# WriteLaTeX vs ShareLaTeX

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf

We are three persons who are going to do a project spanning over a year (math) that will equal 100+ pages of heavy math. This is a collaboration so we are going to need a project history, collaboration account and so on. But we don't want to choose the wrong service. We don't mind paying a bit to have the better service, which one would you go with out of ShareLaTeX and WriteLaTeX, most reliable and so on?

What are your experiences?

Comment: Is there a reason not to include the old-school combo "text editor, compiler and version control system" in your alternatives?

Comment: We're all using 3-4 different computers with varying degrees of stability, we'd like to be able to edit whereever we are and so on. We love the cloud and we would like to stay there. But we did consider it.

Comment: I would use git...but there is a learning curve...

Comment: @EricMalone The old-school way is also compatible with the cloud and with a multiple-machine setup (for example, add your VCS repository in a shared dropbox). Actually, given that "[you]'d like to be able to edit whereever [you] are", it might even be a better idea than the two services you cite, because I'm not sure any of them can be used without an internet connection.